# Swing Containers and Controllers don't abide by the settings applied to them?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans 7 and I'm running into the most unusual situations when designing the Swing Containers and Controllers.  For some unknown reason and at some situation the Containers or Controllers decide to choose their own sizes and dimensions even though I have tried setting these parameters both at the code level and the properties view of each of those containers.  Sometimes I get the Text label of some of my jButtons not showing, sometimes I get a different size JDialog or JPanel even though I both specified them at the design view and at the code level.

Does anyone have any explanation for this odd behaviours or has anyone ran into a problem like that on Netbeans?!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

you probably layed the Containers by built-in `FreeLayout`, or `GridBagLayout`. For specific questions about built-in oprions and funcions is there [Netbeans Forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/), but looks like as witouth answers to the questions,

`Java Desktop Aplication` ([JSR296](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/)) is long time non-supported Framework, I don't know reason and don't know why (to avoid any speculations)

`Java Desktop Aplication` is based on Java `AWT` & `Swing Components`

consider to using standard [Swing JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) layed by standard [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), rather than to reicarnate un_supported `Framework`, about `Swing` is there current (tagged) Swing Forum

maybe is too confortable drag_and_drop `Components` from prepared options, but with bothering customizations (is non_user-friedly, my view)

for good answer you have to  ask question based on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Components are resized based on the current `LayoutManager` rules of your container. Each manager has its own set of rules for managing components' size. For instance, if you are using a BorderLayout ([enter link description here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)), and add a component in the center part, it will use all of the available space, ignoring your size settings (including the minimum/preferred/maximum size). However, if you are using a `GridBagLayout`, you can specify how free space is allocated among components.

It seems that your problem is a layout manger problem. Most of the time, the default manager will not be the one you want to use. Be sure to set the correct `LayoutManager` instance for your needs. If you need more guidance, many tutorials on layout managers are available on the web. [This one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) comes from Oracle (previously written by Sun when it still owned the thing).